# elixir constantize a string to get the module (String.to_module/1)?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm storing some metadata in a session to access different modules based on a string.

Is there any way to do this?

```
String.to_module("MyApp.Vendor")   #=> MyApp.Vendor
String.to_module("MyApp.Customer") #=> MyApp.Customer
```

Then end goal is using the `account_type` to look up the Struct by id to do something specific to that type.

```
account = Repo.get(String.to_module(account_type), account_id)
do_something_with(account)

def do_something_with(%Customer{id: id}) do 
  # yada yada
end

def do_something_with(%Vendor{id: id}) do 
  # something else
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are going to want to use [`String.to_existing_atom`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_existing_atom/1).

```
iex(5)> a = String.to_existing_atom("Elixir.Enum")
Enum
iex(6)> apply(a, :reverse, [[1, 2, 3]])
```

Note that the `Elixir.` prefix is important. If you do not include that, the system will not know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using the `Module` module.

```
iex(1)> Module.concat ["Repo"]
Repo
iex(2)> Module.safe_concat ["Repo"]
Repo
```

Comment: Hi @StevePallen - any particular reason (performance, explicitness, etc.) that this is a better solution? - Thanks for coherence BTW :)

Comment: Couple points @daino3. Use a build in library over rolling your own (not a bit deal here), don't need to worry about the proceed 'Elixir' namespace which you may forget, one interface that can be used for appending name spaces like `Module.concat [MyApp.Base, "Repo"]`. Its a handy API to know, so I would recommend using it even for the simplest cases. And finally, I wanted to make you aware of it :)